# Installing dygraphs with bower install fails on Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dygraphs

Issuing a statement:

```
bower install dygraphs --save
```

And than adding reference to dygraphs:

```
app.import('vendor/dygraphs/src/dygraph.js')
```

Causes an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

on line:

```
import DygraphLayout from './dygraph-layout';
```

And:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
>       at *ember-adater-file*.js:1

What can be the cause of this and how to fix it?

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `app.import` an ES6 module, which is not supported.

Since Ember is discouraging the use of bower, you can try installing dygraphs through npm

```
npm install --save-dev dygraphs
```

And use [ember-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-browserify) to import it.

```
npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
```

Then in your code you can do

```
import Dygraph from "npm:dygraph";
```

And use it right away in your component.